# Getting Error ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to Card.Printer.CardHolder

Tags: c#, wpf, webview2

In `LogPersonDetails` I keep getting an error:

> Error ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to Card.Printer.CardHolder, not sure what is causing this.

The value that is it passing is this:

```
{"FirstName":"ad","LastName":"asd","Email":"asd","CardNumber":"asd"}
```

My theory is that it is doing it twice, but when inspect it i get:

> $exception {"Error converting value "{"FirstName":"ad","LastName":"asd","Email":"asd","CardNumber":"asd"}" to type 'Kiosk.Card.Printer.CardHolder'. Path '', line 1, position 86."}  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException

This is Chromium WebView2 Control and .NET to JavaScript Interop.

Any Ideas?

```csharp
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Windows;
using WebView2.DevTools.Dom;

namespace Kiosk.Card.Printer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += OnWindowLoaded;
        }

        private async void OnWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
            webView.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded += async (s, e) =>
            {
                var devToolsContext = await webView.CoreWebView2.CreateDevToolsContextAsync();

                await devToolsContext.ExposeFunctionAsync("submitData", () =>
                {
                    _ = webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync($"window.getFormData()").ContinueWith(task =>
                    {
                        if (task.Exception == null)
                        {
                            string dataJson = task.Result;
                            if (dataJson != null)
                            {
                                LogPersonDetails(dataJson);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                throw new InvalidOperationException("Result of getFormData() is empty.");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw task.Exception;
                        }
                    });
                });
            };

            webView.NavigateToString(@"
                <h1>WebView2 Concept</h1>
                <input type='text' id='firstName' placeholder='First Name'>
                <input type='text' id='lastName' placeholder='Last Name'>
                <input type='text' id='email' placeholder='Email'>
                <input type='text' id='cardNumber' placeholder='Card Number'>
                <button id='submitDataButton'>Submit Data</button>
                <br/>
                <b>Result:</b>
                <div id='resultDisplay'></div>

                <script>
                    function getFormData() {
                        var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
                        var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
                        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
                        var cardNumber = document.getElementById('cardNumber').value;
                        var person = {
                            FirstName: firstName,
                            LastName: lastName,
                            Email: email,
                            CardNumber: cardNumber
                        };
                        return JSON.stringify(person);
                    }

                    document.getElementById('submitDataButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
                        submitData();
                    }); 

                    function submitData() {
                        console.log('submitData function called');
                        window.submitData();
                    }
                </script>

            ");

        }


        #region Private Methods
        private async void LogPersonDetails(string dataJson)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataJson))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Received empty data.");
                }

                var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CardHolder>(dataJson);
                if (person != null)
                {
                    string displayText = $"Received data: FirstName={person.FirstName}, LastName={person.LastName}, Email={person.Email}, CardNumber={person.CardNumber}";

                    await webView.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(async () =>
                    {
                        await webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.getElementById('resultDisplay').innerHTML = '{displayText}';");
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to deserialize data into CardHolder object.");
                }
            }
            catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException ex)
            {
                string errorMessage = $"Error during deserialization: {ex.Message}";
                await webView.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(async () =>
                {
                    await webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.getElementById('resultDisplay').innerHTML = '{errorMessage}';");
                });
            }
            catch (System.InvalidCastException icex)
            {
                string errorMessage = $"Error during cast: {icex.Message}";
                await webView.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(async () =>
                {
                    await webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.getElementById('resultDisplay').innerHTML = '{errorMessage}';");
                });
            }
        }


        #endregion
    }
    public class CardHolder
    {
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        public string? LastName { get; set; }
        public string? Email { get; set; }
        public string? CardNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the JSON string is double-encoded. This means that it has been JSON encoded twice.
Sorted the fix.